# Exception by building Fieldcat with using a structure

Tags: abap

I try to build a fieldcat-catalog by giving the Function "REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE"  a structure.

Because I had problems with the headerline I must create different internal tables and structures.
With a Loop the programm fills the table without Headerline with the informations from the one with Header.

This works, but if I give my fieldcat-function the structure, 
an Runtimeerror appears when the program try to built the ALV (REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY) , because the Function "REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE" do not fill the fieldcat.

Can someone tell me why? 
Thanks for the help.
here is my code:

```
*Data Declaration

TYPES: BEGIN OF is_ausg.
        INCLUDE STRUCTURE zsd_austab_lief.
        INCLUDE STRUCTURE ws_ausg1.
TYPES: END OF is_ausg.

DATA: is_ausg1  TYPE is_ausg,
      ws_ausg1  TYPE is_ausg,
      it_ausg01 TYPE is_ausg OCCURS 0 WITH HEADER LINE,
      wa_ausg01 TYPE TABLE OF is_ausg,
      gt_fieldcat  TYPE slis_t_fieldcat_alv.   *in the program fieldcat is declared at an other place

*building Fieldcatalog 

LOOP AT it_ausg01 INTO is_ausg1.
    MOVE-CORRESPONDING is_ausg1 TO ws_ausg1.
    APPEND ws_ausg1 TO wa_ausg01.
  ENDLOOP.

  CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE'
    EXPORTING    
          i_structure_name       = 'WS_AUSG1'
          i_client_never_display = 'X'
          i_bypassing_buffer     = 'X'
        CHANGING
          ct_fieldcat            = gt_fieldcat    "<<<<< won´t be filled >>>>>>
        EXCEPTIONS
          inconsistent_interface = 1
          program_error          = 2
          OTHERS                 = 3.

* ALV
  CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'      "<<<< Runtimeerror because of empty gt_fieldcat >>>
    EXPORTING
      i_callback_program       = z_repid
      is_layout                = ps_layout
      it_fieldcat              = gt_fieldcat
      i_save                   = gs_save
      is_variant               = gs_variant
      i_callback_user_command  = 'ALV_USER_COMMAND'
      i_callback_pf_status_set = 'STATUS_SET'
    TABLES
      t_outtab                 = wa_ausg01.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the name of a dictionary structure to `REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE` and similar function modules. They can’t work on arbitrary local types because they rely heavily on the information kept in the dictionary to build the field catalog.

Comment: with a dictionary structure I have the same problem

Comment: Could you please add the revised code to the question?